# Spring data transaction loop

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I use spring boot 2, with spring data jpa and hibernate

In a class I have this code.

```
...

private final MailContentBuilder mailContentBuilder;

private void sendEmail() {

    try {

        List<FactoryEmail> factoryEmails = prepareData();


        if (factoryEmails != null) {
            logger.info(String.valueOf(factoryEmails.size()) + " factories");
        }

        for (FactoryEmail factoryEmail : factoryEmails) {

            String message = mailContentBuilder.build(factoryEmail);

            if (factoryEmail.getEmails() != null && !factoryEmail.getEmails().isEmpty()) {

                logger.info("prepare to sent email to : " + factoryEmail.getFactoryName());

                mailService.sendHtmlMail(factoryEmail.getEmails(), "no conform", message);
                setSampleEmailSent(factoryEmail);

                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
        }
    } catch (MessagingException | InterruptedException ex) {
        logger.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

private void setSampleEmailSent(FactoryEmail factoryEmail) {
    ...
    samplesServices.setEmailsSent(testSampleIdEmailSent);
}
```

In SampleService Class

```
@Transactional
public void setEmailsSent(Map<String, List<SampleId>> testSampleIdEmailSent) {
    ...
    repository.save(....);
}
```

Because I loop, If one fail, I don't want to rollback for everybody. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

That sort of approach should work well, albeit in some cases you might need `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` instead?

The more programmatic approach *used to be* [TransactionTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html) although I'm not sure if there's a more recent approach than this.